# How to filter 'NaN' in Pig

Tags: apache-pig, nan

I have data that has some rows that look like this:

(1655,var0,var1,NaN)

The first column is an ID, the second and third come from the correlation. The fourth column is the correlation value (from using the COR function).
I would like to filter these rows.

From the Apache Pig documentation, I was under the impression that NaN is equivalent to a null. Therefore I added this to my code:

```
filter_corr = filter correlation by (corr IS NOT NULL);
```

This obviously did not work since apparently Pig does not treat null and NaN in the same way.
I would like to know what is the correct way to filter NaN since it is not clear from the Pig documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: `NULL` generally means the absence of an object.  If you have an actual `NaN` in 4th column in your relation, pig will read this as a string of letters.  Try filtering with `filter correlation by corr == 'NaN'` and see what it returns.

Comment: I usually do this by reading the column as a chararray column. If I check for the string 'NaN' while the column is defined as an int or a double, I get an error. I was hoping to find a better way to do this intermediate step.

Comment: What I'm asking is does your first column look like `(1655, var0, var1, NaN)` or `(1655, var0, var1, )` ?

Comment: It looks like (1655, var0, var1, NaN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually you could specify your column as chararray in you schema and Filter with a `not matches 'NaN'`

Or evenly if you want to replace your NaNs by something else, you put the chararray in your schema as previously and then :

`Data = FOREACH Data GENERATE ..., (correlation matches 'NaN' ? 0 : (double) correlation), ...`

I hope this could help, good luck ;)

Comment: This is close enough to what I went with, so I'll give you the "accept" :)

Answer (score 0):

You could read in the data as one `chararray` line and the use a udf to parse the rows.  I made a dataset it looks like this

```
1665,var0,var1,NaN
1453,var2,var3,5.432
3452,var4,var5,7.654
8765,var6,var7,NaN
```

Create UDF

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
### name of file: udf.py ###

@outputSchema("id:int, col2:chararray, col3:chararray, corr:float")
def format_input(line):
    parsed = line.split(',')
    if parsed[len(parsed) - 1] == 'NaN'
        parsed.pop()
        parsed.append(None)
    return tuple(parsed)
```

Then in the pig shell

```
$ pig -x local
grunt>

/* register udf */
register 'udf.py' using jython as udf;

data = load 'file' as (line:chararray);
A = foreach data generate FLATTEN(udf.format_input(line));
filtered = filter A by corr is not null;
dump filtered
```

output

```
(1453,var2,var3,5.432)
(3452,var4,var5,7.654)
```

Comment: NB : You should avoid UDF if you can, cause since Pig can't see what's in your UDF the Auto-Prune couldn't be achieved :)

Answer (score 0):

I've gone with this solution:

```
filter_corr = filter data by (corr != 'NaN');
data1 = foreach filter_corr generate ID, (double)corr as double_corr;
```

I renamed the column and reassigned the data type from chararray to double.

I appreciate the responses but I cannot use UDFs during prototyping due to a limitation in the UI that I am using (Cloudera)